# How much duplicate content percentage is considered as bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

If a site contains 94% of unique content and remaining 6% of the content coming under duplicate, then can it be considered as bad for SEO?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 6% of duplicate content on a page, you have no risk for SEO (especially if you have more content on this page).

All sites have a little percentage of duplicate content between several internal pages, it's generated by CMS in general and it's normal.